# Mixed Model Type-III Sums of Squares- R vs SPSS

Tags: r, mixed-model, spss, sums-of-squares

The age old question of comparing sums of squares (SS) between programs has reared its ugly head again.

I am trying to replicate output in SPSS, that was computed using Type 3 Sums of Squares, in R.

I understand that with multiple regressions, there are several ways to get Type 3 SS in R (to match Type 3 output from SPSS).

However, I am running a mixed model using aov (which uses Type 1 SS) and even when I try all the "usual" fixes," my estimates don't match the Type 3 SS output from SPSS.

First of all, when I run the SPSS syntax using "/METHOD=SSTYPE(1)" the results match those I get using this code:

```
  mymodel<-aov(data=longdat,  DV ~ 1 + Task + Cue + Compatibility + Cue:Task + Compatibility:Task + Cue:Compatibility + Cue:Compatibility:Task + Error(subject/Cue/Compatibility/Cue*Compatibility))
  summary(mymodel)
```

So I know the analyses are the same when they use Type 1 SS.

However, when I use:

```
 options(contrasts = c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))
 tt<-lm(DV ~ 1 + Task + Cue + Compatibility + Cue:Task  + Compatibility:Task + Cue:Compatibility + Cue:Compatibility:Task + 1/subject/Cue/Compatibility    /(Cue*Compatibility), data=longdat)
 drop1(tt, ~., test="F")
```

The results do not match the SPSS Type 3 output.

In attempts to get matching output, I have also tried the Anova function (which can give Type 3 SS)

```
  Anova(mymodel, type=3, test.statistic="F")
```

but I get this error `"Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 'data' argument is of the wrong type."`

I have also tried using `lmer`.

Can someone help me get Type 3 Sums of Squares for a mixed model in R?

Thank you!

Comment: (I changed the title a bit adding the term `Type-III` so it is more obvious what you are asking for. I hope you do not mind, please feel free to change it too.)

Comment: You showed R syntax you did but did not show the SPSS syntax. Why so? How can one follow you?

Comment: Unfortunately the SPSS syntax is not mine to share. Apologies for any confusion!

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest thing to do will be to simply use the functions [mixed](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/afex/html/mixed.html) and [aov.car](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/afex/html/aov.car.html) from the package [afex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/afex/). Please note that to calculate the degrees of freedom these functions use the Kenward-Rogers approximation. Other functions (or other software in general) might use Satterthwaite approximations. A very interesting discussion on Type-III sums was done in this site and is available: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6208/should-i-include-an-argument-to-request-type-iii-sums-of-squares-in-ezanova).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! I tried to use the mixed function but my random effects were giving different results than the SPSS output. I ended up using the `ezAnova` function with this code (at the advice of a colleague).

```
ezANOVA( data = longdat, dv = DV, wid = subject, 
    within = .(Cue,Compatibility),   between = Task, type = 3, detailed=TRUE)
```

and the `anova_out` function in the `schoRsch` package to get a partial eta squared.

These two functions allowed me to replicate the SPSS mixed ANOVA output.

Comment: +1. No problem. And thank you for posting your solution.  It creates a good resource for future users! :) (I formatted your code again a bit.)